# how can I click only one of the elements in a class with multiple elements?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework

ok so I cannot share the website I'm trying to automate  but I'll share a screen shots of the inspect view.

[image]

ill add the code i used and the log i got from it

[image]
as you can see the class: data-command has three elements within in the number is dynamic but I need to click on the last one, i do not want to use absolut xpath as the class: data-command is dynamic.
ill add the code i used and the log i got from it

how do i click the last element

```
    #@{element_value}=    Get WebElements    class:data-value
    @{elements_name}=    Get WebElements    class:data-label 
    @{element_commands}=    Get WebElements    class:data-command
    WHILE    ${i} < 5
        #Log To Console    ${element_commands[${i}]}
        Click Element    ${element_commands[${i}]}
        Sleep    5s
        #Capture Page Screenshot
        Run Keyword And Warn On Failure        Page Should Contain    ${graph}
        ${i}=    Evaluate    ${i} + ${one}
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with robot framework, but is case `data-command` class is a unique locator, the following XPath will give you the last child inside that element:

```
"(//div[@class='data-command']//*)[last()]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get elements store it in collection/list and then get the last one and click it:

```
List<WebElement> elements= driver.findElements(By.css(".data-command"));

element = elements.get(list.size() - 1); //Click only the last in the list
```

Comment: sorry had forgotten to add it but yes i am storing the elements in a list have edited  the code to show it now